# return and echo in the same function

Tags: php

I'm trying to add some HTML code via echo inside this PHP code:

```
    if( $quantity == 0 ) 
        return __("ZERO ITEMS");
    elseif( $quantity > 0 && $quantity <= 5 ) 
        return $quantity;
    elseif( $quantity > 5 ) 
        return __("OVER 5 ITEMS");
```

When the $quantity is 3, for example, I want to return the quantity and also have the word "ITEMS" echo'd after it. So "3 ITEMS" instead of just "3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are 3 items, your control will go to `else if`.

You are returning only `$quantity` that is number.

You need to concatenate the string `ITEMS` after `$quantity`

```
...
elseif( $quantity > 0 && $quantity <= 5 ) 
        return $quantity . ' ITEMS';
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me and for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if ( $quantity == 0 ) 
    return __("ZERO ITEMS");
else if( $quantity > 0 && $quantity <= 5 ) {
    $itemText = ($quantity == 1) ? 'ITEM' : 'ITEMS';
    echo $quantity . ' ' . $itemText;
    return $quantity . ' ' . $itemText;
} else if( $quantity > 5 ) 
    return __("OVER 5 ITEMS");
```

You can have `1`, so it's interesting to show `ITEM` or `ITEMS`

Comment: you should only have the return $quantity line, the one before it, with echo, should not be there. and $itemText should be outside of the if statements.

Comment: Depending your code, you can have the echo. Based on your question title. The `$itemText`  will be used only on that `else if` block. There are no needs for the others blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below.

```
$post_str = 'ITEMS';
if( $quantity == 0 ) 
        return __("ZERO ".$post_str);
    elseif( $quantity > 0 && $quantity <= 5 ) 
        return $quantity.' '.$post_str;
    elseif( $quantity > 5 ) 
        return __("OVER 5 ".$post_str);
```